# timer depends on capslock

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010

im using visual studio 2010 c++, and im making a windows form application. my question is how can i make a timer that will start and stop depends on the capslock status, it's like it will start when capslock is on and stop when capslock is off. LIke something like this

```
public void keyDownEvent(... )
    {
       if (capslockOn != 0)
           timer1->enabled = true
       else
           timer1->enabled = false
    }
```

Comment: How is the _"Visual Studio 2010"_ relevant to your question? Visual Studio 2010 is an IDE. Elaborate what kind of framework you use to create an application? For example, is it MFC, is it Qt, or whatever?

Comment: Is this question about C++? I C#?

Comment: read the first line. It is a C++ winforms

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can use the Windows API function `GetKeyState` to determine the state of the CAPS LOCK key:

```
SHORT WINAPI GetKeyState(
  _In_  int nVirtKey
);
```

Test:

```
if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001)!=0)
  // Caps Lock is ON
else
  // Caps Lock is OFF
```

where `VK_CAPITAL` is 0x14. The low-order bit is switched on or off, indicating the state of the key.